# Mocking the file system within a test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js

I've been using this method to test file-system functions as an alternative to [`mock-fs`](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs) due to [its lack of symlink support](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/53). I'd love to hear what others think and the possible dangers, pitfalls, or improvements.

```
var CWD = process.cwd()
var assert = require('assert')
var path = require('path')
var os = require('os')
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'))
// note this is a custom verison of fs-extra :(

// [[fileName, contents], expectation]
var files = [
  ['hello.js', ''],
  ['folder/file-require-local.js', 'var local = require(\'../file-require-sibling.js\')'],
  ['file-require-sibling.js', 'var local = require(\'./file-require-underscore.js\')'],
  ['file-require-underscore.js', 'var underscore = require(\'underscore\')'],
  ['file-import-underscore.js', 'import underscore from \'underscore\''],
  ['file-require-path.js', 'var path = require(\'path\')'],
  ['file-require-local.js', 'var hello = require(\'./hello.js\')'],
  ['file-import-local.js', 'import hello from \'./hello.js\''],
  ['file-require-json.js', 'var pkg = require(\'./package.json\')'],
  ['file-multi-file.js', (function () {
    var file = []
    file.push('var underscore = require(\'underscore\')')
    file.push('var path = require(\'path\')')
    file.push('var hello = require(\'./hello.js\')')
    return file.join('\n')
  }())]
]

/* global describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it */

var ROOT_DESC = 'recursive-deps'
var TEST_DIR = path.join(os.tmpdir(), ROOT_DESC)

describe(ROOT_DESC, function () {

  before(function () {
    fs.emptyDirSync(TEST_DIR)
    process.chdir(TEST_DIR)
  })

  beforeEach(function () {
    return Promise.map(files, function (file) {
      return fs.ensureFileAsync.apply(null, file)
    })
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    fs.emptyDirSync(TEST_DIR)
  })

  after(function () {
    process.chdir(CWD)
    fs.removeSync(TEST_DIR)
  })

  it('should have mock file system', function () {
    var dir = fs.readdirSync(TEST_DIR)
    var expected = [
      'file-import-local.js',
      'file-import-underscore.js',
      'file-multi-file.js',
      'file-require-json.js',
      'file-require-local.js',
      'file-require-path.js',
      'file-require-sibling.js',
      'file-require-underscore.js',
      'folder',
      'hello.js'
    ]
    assert.equal(process.cwd().indexOf(TEST_DIR) > -1, true)
    assert.deepEqual(dir, expected)
  })

})
```

Comment: The symlink issue is fixed now. I'm curious what is the purpose of simulating file system? You could use mocking, to represent behaviour of reading a file system - sinon library is good example. It's a bad practise to unit test on specific environment, since it might not work elsewhere. In your case test would probably fail in Windows.